# How to mount a folder on one drive as a folder on a different drive?

Tags: windows, windows-8-preview

I've mounted a drive as a folder, mapped a folder as a drive, and mapped one fold on one drive to a different folder on the same drive, but I have not been able to get a folder on one drive to map to a folder on a different drive.

I am running 64-bit Windows 8.

I tried the [Junction](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768) tool, and the new [MKLink](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194%28v=WS.10%29.aspx) command introduced in Windows 7. They don't appear to allow mapping between drives. Wondering if maybe combining a few techniques will produce the desired result.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have a Windows 8 machine to test this, but it works in Windows 7.

If I have a folder on drive **E:** called **MP3**, I can create a directory junction (**C:\Music**) like this:

```
mklink /j "C:\Music" "E:\MP3"
```

Browsing to **C:\Music** in Windows Explorer shows me what is in **E:\MP3**.

Comment: Yes, that did it. I had a security issue on the target folder which was causing me grief.